# Trouble following recursive code

Tags: java, recursion

Just trying to understand how this code works. Say the integer is 4, I understand that 4 is checked against the base case and then the method calls itself again this time with the integer 3 and then same pattern occurs until the integer is 1. My question is how is the summation part being done? What would be the final result?

```
public int sum(int num)
{
   int result;
   if (num == 1)
      result = 1;
   else
      result = num + sum(num-1);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: An explanation could be given, but perhaps the best way to understand how recursion is working here would be to add a breakpoint to your `sum()` method and then see for yourself how it works.

Comment: this is a weird one! is this some kind of excercise for school or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you realize based on your post, the magic happens here: `result = num + sum(num-1);` Think of it as a chain of method calls. Logically, the whole process could be represented like this:

```
sum(4);
```

evaluates to

```
4 + sum(3);
```

which evaluates to

```
4 + 3 + sum(2);
```

which evaluates to

```
4 + 3 + 2 + sum(1);
```

which evaluates to

```
4 + 3 + 2 + 1
```

which is equal to

```
10
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens here:

```
result = num + sum(num-1);
```

together with

```
return result;
```

Iteration *n* calls sum() again (triggering iteration *n+1*). The result of *n+1* is returned; and added to *n*; giving the result of *n-1* (because of the later return statement).

And for the record: I did not include the final solution in my answer; as you can figure that easily by yourself; either by **running** that code; or by using a pen and a piece of paper to "run" this code "manually".

Answer (score 1):

The summation happens as the recursive calls return back up the stack. See here:

```
             sum(4)   # The initial function call
               |
          |---------------|
          | 4 + sum(4-1)  |     # num + recursive call
                  |
              |---------------|
              | 3 + sum(3-1)  |  # the next num + the next recursive call
                      |
                  |---------------|
                  | 2 + sum(2-1)  |
                          |
                        |---|
                        | 1 |    # Base case num == 1
```

If you populate each recursive `sum(...)` call with the value below it, what do you get? The sums added up. That's where the addition occurs.

Trace this and find out what the value should be for yourself. Or, run the code.